# Vectorising the python code for modifying masks used in Image segmentation

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on an Image segmentation challenge. I have masks which have 5 labels(0, 1, 2, 3, 4) and the layout of one such mask(2D matrix) is :

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 2 2
 1 1 1 1 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2
 3 3 3 3 3 3
 4 4 4 4 4 4]
```

I want to merge several classes such that the modified mask looks like :

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 1
 0 0 0 0 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1
 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2]
```

Merged 0 and 1 to 0.
Changed 2 to 1.
Merged 3 and 4, changed them to 2.

I have implemented a looped version and it is taking a lot of time as the dimension of my mask is (601, 462, 951).

```
for i in range(0, dim.shape[0]):
  for j in range(0, dim.shape[1]):
    for k in range(0, dim.shape[2]):
      if dim[i, j, k] in (0, 2):
        dim[i, j, k] = 1

      if dim[i, j, k] == 3:
        dim[i, j, k] = 2

      if dim[i, j, k] in (4, 8):
        dim[i, j, k] = 3

      if dim[i, j, k] == 9:
        dim[i, j, k] = 4
```

I can't find any way to vectorize my code so that I can remove the loops.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean with `Merged 0 and 1 to 0`?

Comment: I mean I replaced 1s with 0s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for a concise solution, which allows you to select from a `choicelist` given a list of conditions:

```
np.select([a==1, a==2, (a==3)|(a==4)], [0,1,2])

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Comment: I also tried np.where(), that also works relatively fast.

Comment: @TusharGautam Make sure to try out other posted solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
a[a == 1] = 0
a[a == 2] = 1
a[(a == 3) | (a == 4)] = 2
```

where `a` is your numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a `mapper`

You could create a mapping array and then simply indexing with the input array would give us the desired output -

```
mapper = np.array([0,0,1,2,2])
out = mapper[a] # a is input array
```

Timings for all posted solutions with the same given shape - `(601, 462, 951))` -

```
In [60]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,5,(601, 462, 951))

# @yatu's soln
In [61]: %timeit np.select([a==1, a==2, (a==3)|(a==4)], [0,1,2])
1 loop, best of 3: 5 s per loop

# Posted in this post
In [62]: %%timeit
    ...: mapper = np.array([0,0,1,2,2])
    ...: out = mapper[a]
1 loop, best of 3: 849 ms per loop

# @Austin's soln
In [63]: %%timeit
    ...: a[a == 1] = 0
    ...: a[a == 2] = 1
    ...: a[(a == 3) | (a == 4)] = 2
1 loop, best of 3: 1.04 s per loop
```

**Further boost with lower-precision dtype**

Since, the output would have labels - `0,1,2`, we can safely use `UINT8` as the output datatype and gain huge performance boost. So, it would be -

```
mapper = np.array([0,0,1,2,2],dtype=np.uint8)
out = mapper[a]
```

Timings -

```
In [66]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,5,(601, 462, 951))

In [67]: %%timeit
    ...: mapper = np.array([0,0,1,2,2],dtype=np.uint8)
    ...: out = mapper[a]
1 loop, best of 3: 380 ms per loop
```